# Difference between: std::make_unique<char>(size_t size) and std::make_unique<char[]>(size_t size)?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14

I was implementing the circular array data structure whose code looks like this:

```
struct CircularArrayException : public std::exception {
    std::string msg;

    CircularArrayException(const std::string arg_msg) 
    : msg{"CircularArrayException: " + arg_msg} {}

    const char * what () const throw () {
        return msg.c_str();
    }
};

template <typename T>
class CircularArray {
public:
    const size_t array_size;
    std::unique_ptr<T> uptr_arr;

    size_t occupied_size = 0;
    int front_idx = -1;
    int back_idx = -1;
 
    CircularArray(const CircularArray& ca) = delete;

    CircularArray& operator=(const CircularArray& ca) = delete;

    CircularArray(
        const size_t arg_array_size
    ):  array_size{arg_array_size} {
        uptr_arr = std::make_unique<T>(array_size);
    };
};
```

After the implementation I tested the implementation with `CircularArray<char>` and it works fine.
But, then I realized that we use `std::make_unique<char[]>(num_elements)` to declare a unique_ptr to an array as opposed to `std::make_unique<char>(num_elements)`. But, even then the code seems to work fine. I looked the documentation of `std::make_unique` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) and couldn't understand the explanation of the (2)nd signature. Can anyone help me out to understand the difference and why my code works?

Here is the what is written on cppreference for the (2) signature:

```
template< class T >
unique_ptr<T> make_unique( std::size_t size );
```

(2) (since C++14)
(only for array types with unknown bound)

Constructs an array of unknown bound T. This overload participates in overload resolution only if T is an array of unknown bound. The function is equivalent to: `unique_ptr<T>(new typename std::remove_extent<T>::type[size]())`

Here is the goldbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/K9h3qTeTW

Comment: Did you run this in a memory debugger like Valgrind? In any case, I don't think `make_unique()` takes a size parameter, so the parameter is only used to init the created object. Just step through the code with a debugger to find out or study the docs at cppreference.com. BTW: I'd question your choice of using dynamica allocation like that when you could just build on `vector`. Consider submitting your code (once it works properly) at codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: there's too much code for your question! try a minimal and easy to reproduce code including only two unique pointers :) that would motivate people a lot more to read and answer your questoin  :)))

Comment: Thanks for comments. I will minimize the question.

Comment: `vector` is a better option, I would use that. But, still I want to know what is this (2) signature of `make_unique` means.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt make_unique takes the size parameter iff the type is an array with unknown bounds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::make_unique<char>(65);` creates a pointer to a *single* character initialised with the value `65` (`'A'`). `std::make_unique<char[]>(65)` creates an array with 65 elements.

If you run this code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto a = std::make_unique<char>(65);
    std::cout << *a << "\n";
    auto b = std::make_unique<char[]>(65);
    std::cout << (int)b[0] << "\n";
}
```

It'll print `A` for the first one and an undefined value for the second one (possibly 0) as the array elements are uninitialised.

Your code "works" by chance, using any more than 1 element of your "array" will cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: It works properly. Here is the link: https://godbolt.org/z/K9h3qTeTW

Comment: No, it does not. As Alan explained – you are writing to memory you don't own. It just happens to not crash because you write such short strings. If you write more than a few chars, your code crashes: https://godbolt.org/z/e18rGbsPv

Comment: So you mean to say, it is possible to write unowned memory in C++. Don't you think it is memory unsafe?

Comment: @KishoreKaushal It does not work properly. Here is the link: https://godbolt.org/z/57zdx3r8b Only a compiler option was changed.

Comment: @KishoreKaushal C and C++ are famously memory unsafe, by design.

Comment: Yes, c++ does no bounds checking, if you write only a small amount out of bounds you might not overwrite anything important and your code appears to work, write a few more bytes though and your code will likely start crashing or worse silently misbehave

Comment: Thanks guys. I now know what I was doing. That was a good learning. Lessons learnt: in C++ you can access unowned memory. XD